# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe

Google chrome gives me this message when I am using google maps frame on my contacts page:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://localhost/igames/index.php?page=contact_us&&lang=rus from frame
>   with URL
>   http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=44.590467,-105.820312&spn=10.747987,23.269043&t=m&z=6&vpsrc=6&output=embed.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You should use the Google Maps API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Answer (score 6):

For reference, it would seems to be a bug in Google Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43173

Ben Lee's workaround seems to be the only workaround as long as it doesn't get fixed in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in Chrome. To get rid of it, use the following code:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var centerNL = new google.maps.LatLng(52.093008,5.12);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 11,
  center: centerNL,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  navigationControl: true,
  navigationControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  }
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
</script>
```

Replace LatLng and zoom with your own values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using chrome on a page with a google map iframe (untouched and pasted from the google maps site).

for me this problem was solved just by navigating my site with the www. in front of it, in spite of  the url not being mencioned in the iframe or in the registration of the place.

this looks like a google maps bug.

till they solve i will redirect my trafic to the www. version (thats is the exact same).

Answer (score -4):

If you use an `iframe` then you get this error. Try to change your code to use an `object` tag as follows:

```
<object width="560" height="340">
 <param name="movie"
        value="http://www.youtube.com/v/JTttSMPz3Y4&hl=en_GB&fs=1&"></param> 
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
 <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/JTttSMPz3Y4&hl=en_GB&fs=1&" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        allowscriptaccess="always"
        allowfullscreen="true"
        width="560"
        height="340"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: xDDD dude, how the heck is this even related to the question?